# Python iterating over a list in parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, iteration

I have a list created with no more than 8 items in it, right now I loop over the item with a standard for loop "for item in list:" I am wondering if there is a way to check all of the elements at the exact same time? I have seen some posts about using zip to iterate over 2 lists at the same time which could help.

If there is no way to iterate over a lists elements at the same time I would guess I need to split one single list into 4 separate lists and iterate 2 at the same time using zip and do the other 2 on a separate thread, that seems like it could be a clunky fix though.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**
Sorry to be vague, I have a list

```
apples = ['green', 'green', 'green', 'red']
```

right now I use a for loop to go over each element,

```
for apple in apples:
    checkAppleColour(apple)
    #Do some more stuff depending on colour....
```

right now it loops over each element in apple one by one, what I would like to be able to do is check each of the items at the exact same time for a colour check as every millisecond counts (example code used, but principle is exactly the same for what I am trying to achieve).

Performance is key here I don't mind if its threading I have to use, but I need maximum speed / efficiency for checking each element and my guess is parallelism is the way to do it, I am just not quite sure how.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by `check all of the elements at the exact same time` ? What do you actually want to do ?

Comment: Can you add some example code to clarify exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I'll second @Overdrivr what are you trying to acheive/do? are you looking for multiprocessing solution? are you trying to compare several elements to one another?

Comment: Completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: `zip` is only used when you need data from two lists in the same `for` loop, it doesn't do any parallel processing. Start a thread for each element of your list if you want them processed independently and in parallel

Comment: `zip` doesn't have to be only two sequences.

Comment: Updated the original post, sorry to be so vague.

Comment: `my guess is parallelism is the way to do it` do not guess, profile and measure it.

Answer (score 7):

If you can map a function onto the list, parallelism is easy.

```
def addOne (x):
    return x + 1
```

The default map does things on one thread.

```
map(addOne, range(1, 4)) #When iterated over produces [2, 3, 4]
```

If your problem is a map, it means that it's trivially parallel.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool()
pool.map(addOne, range(1, 4)) ##When iterated over produces [2, 3, 4]
```

This uses multiple processes. `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` is a thread pool. See [this article for a great introduction](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/) to the rationale behind both.